# JTextLabel mouse events - MouseListener doesn't work as supposed

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, mouselistener

I have little problem with my Java program. I have two `JTextFields` and I want to clear both of them when I click on them (The one that is clicked should be cleared - just like on the websites, when you have to login, there is a text field that says **username**, and when you click to type in it, the text disapears). The text field `naz` works fine, the other one  `imie` is constructed in exactly same way, but doesn't work I don't know where the problem is. I tried changing order of adding them to `JPanel`, but it didn't fix the problem.

Another question - since I am new to Java programming, is this good way of creating such GUI? Any advices?

Below is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MojGUI{
    JTextField im;
    JTextField naz;


    public static void main(String[] args){
        MojGUI aaa = new MojGUI();
        aaa.doRoboty();
    }

    public void doRoboty(){
        JFrame ramka = new JFrame();
        ramka.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel podpanel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel podpanel2 = new JPanel();

        JLabel imie = new JLabel("Imie:");
        JLabel nazwisko = new JLabel("Naziwsko:");

        im = new JTextField("Wpisz imie", 10);
        imie.addMouseListener(new KlikIm());
        naz = new JTextField("Wpisz nazwisko", 10);
        naz.addMouseListener(new KlikNaz());

        podpanel1.add(imie);
        podpanel1.add(im);
        podpanel2.add(nazwisko);
        podpanel2.add(naz);

        panel.add(podpanel1);
        panel.add(podpanel2);

        ramka.setContentPane(panel);
        ramka.setSize(300, 300);

        ramka.setVisible(true);
    }

    class KlikIm implements MouseListener{
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            im.setText("");
        };
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){};
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){};
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){};
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){};
    }

    class KlikNaz implements MouseListener{
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            naz.setText("");
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){};
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){};
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){};
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){};
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a typo error on stack overflow, but isn't it because perhaps you are adding a mouse listener to the imie JLabel instead of the im JTextField?

Comment: That's why I like consulting my code with other people - I wouldn't notice that mispelling... Unfortunately I do not have any Java programmers around.. thank you

Comment: You wouldn't get problem if you were using Javafx, the n'ext step after swing, it clearly better in all ways i thing, you have more and more features ! And for your case you'll get a "prompttext" property in TextFiled of javafx, it's a grey text like as we know will not appear once we click on the TextField, and i look for in swingDoc but i didn't find

Comment: Thank you azro. But JavaFX is suppoerted on Java 8, I recently came across this and I am going to get familiar with it :)